# kill a user's program if disk usage exceeds 98% in linux

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I know I can find the amount of space left in my home directory using 'df -h' in linux. But is it possible to write a script/python program which constantly monitors disk usage in my home directory and kills all currently running programs with my user name if my disk usage exceeds 98%. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 server

Comment: Yes it is possible. Use a crontab or a tool like monit, check `df`, and use `pkill -u`. But I would rather send an email to the sysadmin when the disk usage reach ~85% and take rational decisions (clean some logs, move backups...).

Comment: @rdupz Tool is a good way..but as I am a student I also want to learn..is it possible to write a program to do the same...so that I may kill all my processes(associated with my user name) when disk usage exceeds 98%

Comment: Ok so here are some weapons: bash, cron, mount (to know home partition), df (use it with grep and awk), pkill (check the -u option).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of lurking, adding up space usage over and over (which requires repeated scans of your entire home directory hierarchy) and killing all your processes, you should just set yourself up with a [disk quota.](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ch-disk-quotas.html) If your programs get out of hand, the OS will choke their access to the disk and you won't have to do a thing.

Or if it's a particular program writing to a single file that gets out of hand, you can use `ulimit -f` to cap the size of the files it can create. (See `help ulimit` at the `bash` prompt.)

Comment: Cool idea. But I really want to learn as a student if it is possible to check disk space usage and then kill my program...I am really curious to find out if it would really work...if possible can you please help me with the same...I succeed in getting the memory usage using: "df -h | grep '/home' | sed 's/:/ /' | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/%/ /'| awk '{print $1}'"

Comment: Sure it would work, it's just not a great way to do it. (Note that `df` cannot tell you about your own space usage-- just the total space on the partition containing `/home`). Look up `python.subprocess` (to call `df` from python), `os.kill`, and `time.sleep`.